# Отступ после элемента tr (table-row)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать отступ после tr, по типу обычного margin, для одного конкретного табличного ряда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот **простая таблица**:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Сделать отступ после тега `tr`, который служит контейнером для создания строки таблицы, по типу обычного `margin` для какой-то одной конкретной табличной строки нельзя, такой возможности в CSS для таблиц не существует.

Но мы можем использовать другие варианты, чтобы добиться нужного нам результата. Структуру HTML при этом мы не трогаем, она у нас остается неизменной. Меняем только стиль CSS. Вот для примера **три варианта**:

**Вариант с Grid:**

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

table td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

table td:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(4) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Вариант с Flex:**

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

table td {
  flex: 3 1 auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

table td:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(4) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Вариант с inline-block:**

```css
table, tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table tr {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

table td:nth-child(3) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(4) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin` - никак. Можно изменить `padding`.
Также можно свободно стилизовать `td` внутри нужной `tr`